# Android Studio Emulator error: Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line, android-emulator, performance-testing

I am using Windows command prompt to run this Android Studio emulator. It is able to open the emulator, but got error message Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2

What does this error means? And how to solve the error? Mind help. I am new to this. Purpose to use the emulator is only to do mobile performance testing on VuGen LoadRunner. Can refer the screenshot at link below. Thanks

[Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pih5F.png)